# Angularjs - How to filter objects by multiple values in their properties

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-filter

I am having different objects like in the code sample below. I have some checkboxes that filters based on brewer, style, aroma and country. It is filtering only if it has one property in the array.

What is the best solution to make the filter work based on all the elements in the array? I checked some other questions and I couldn't find anything related.
It will be great if any of you could help me.

Thanks.

sample of the code here: [http://pastie.org/10787362](http://pastie.org/10785071)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` method of Javascript `Array()` object.
For example:

```
$scope.filteredNames = $scope.names.filter(function(element) {
   return
     'brewer1' in element.brewers &&
     'aroma1' in element.aromas
   ;
});
```

`$scope.filteredNames` should contain all `names` with 'brewer1' value in `brewers` property AND 'aroma1' value in `aromas` property...

Comment: You definitely should try to simplify your pastie, keeping only the minimum set of data and code, to help people help you...

Comment: Still too much code and data. You can do better... :-)

Comment: to be more clear: the problem occurs when the property of the beers objects has multiple values in its array